# What server side caching can be used with Joomla 2.5.x?

Tags: joomla-2.5, cache, server

I'm currently looking at different server caching options for Joomla. I'm not ready to upgrade to Joomla 3.x yet, so I'm just looking at options for 2.5.x

Redis was looking good, but based on the discussion at https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/3615 it seems Redis won't be available until Joomla 3.4?

So, I was wondering, what options are there for server side caching in Joomla 2.5.x ?

**EDIT1:** By cache systems, I mean Redis, Xcache, APC, Memcache/d, etc

**EDIT2:** I will have root access/administrative privileges on the server.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the systems you mention, but what are the benefits of using a 3rd party caching system instead of the built-in Joomla cache system?

Comment: I'm not sure that 3rd party is the correct term for this. I believe Joomla has to use the caching system of the server, but Joomla is not compatible with all server caching systems. I'm researching the caching systems that Joomla can use....

Comment: Varnish is supported through a commercial extension, it might be worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

There are various methods that can be used.

### Method 1:

You can download and installing a caching Plugin. Personally, I like to use [JCH Optimize](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/site-performance/12088). However, be very careful when using minimizing and combining JS files. You may find some errors in the console and have to excludes a file or 2 from the plugin.

### Method 2:

There are 2 different types of caching with Joomla.

Page caching, which can be found in **Plugins >> System >> Cache**. This basically cache each individual page. I'm not sure if this applies for 2.5 but according to the Docs, it will only cache for guests, not logged in users.

View caching, which can be found in the Global Configuration of your Joomla backend. This caches each view of a component, however will only work if the component developers has added the cache feature.

### Method 3:

Some hosting providers have their own caching system. I know that Siteground have 3 different types or caching, depending on the aggressiveness one would like to use. Might be worth look yout your hosting control panel to see if there are any options.

### Method 4 (browser):

Your your htaccess file. You will firstly need to rename `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess`.

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

there was also a good article written for Joomla's Managine by Ofer Cohen:

http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-oct-2012/item/903-simple-performance-guide

Comment: Sorry Lodder, this is good information, but it isn't quite what I meant. Maybe I am confused a little bit about how the things you mentioned interact with the server's caching mechanisms. I wanted to know which server caching systems (for example REDIS, predis, memcached, APC, etc) can be used with Joomla 2.5.x. I originally assumed that I could use any of these, but it would appear that that isn't the case.

Comment: I imagine the things you mentioned use/plug in to the cache system I am researching.

Comment: Ahh I see now. I haven't looked into caching systems you have mentioned apart from memcache, so I wouldn't be the best person to answer this :/